# Codeigniter Linux Failed to open stream: Permission denied on creating image file/qr code in 777 mode temp directory

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter, permissions

Please help me. I am trying to create a temporary png image file/qr code in `/var/www/html/temp` folder using phpqrcode library by embedding an image from `/var/www/assets/images`. But it keeps showing error like this :

```
A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  imagepng(/var/www/html/temp/10012023_053321_pm_qrcode.png): failed to open stream: Permission denied</p>
<p>Filename: phpqrcode/qrimage.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 43</p>


    <p>Backtrace:</p>
    
        
    
        
    
        
    
        
            <p style="margin-left:10px">
            File: /var/www/html/application/libraries/phpqrcode/qrimage.php<br />
            Line: 43<br />
            Function: imagepng          </p>

        
    
        
            <p style="margin-left:10px">
            File: /var/www/html/application/libraries/phpqrcode/qrencode.php<br />
            Line: 494<br />
            Function: png           </p>

        
    
        
            <p style="margin-left:10px">
            File: /var/www/html/application/libraries/phpqrcode/qrencode.php<br />
            Line: 286<br />
            Function: encodePNG         </p>

        
    
        
            <p style="margin-left:10px">
            File: /var/www/html/application/helpers/portalsdm_helper.php<br />
            Line: 145<br />
            Function: png           </p>

        
    
        
            <p style="margin-left:10px">
            File: /var/www/html/application/controllers/Sestama.php<br />
            Line: 465<br />
            Function: create_qr         </p>

        
    
        
    
        
            <p style="margin-left:10px">
            File: /var/www/html/index.php<br />
            Line: 315<br />
            Function: require_once          </p>

        
    

</div>
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  imagecreatefrompng(/var/www/html/temp/10012023_053321_pm_qrcode.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory</p>
<p>Filename: helpers/portalsdm_helper.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 149</p>


    <p>Backtrace:</p>
    
        
    
        
    
        
    
        
            <p style="margin-left:10px">
            File: /var/www/html/application/helpers/portalsdm_helper.php<br />
            Line: 149<br />
            Function: imagecreatefrompng            </p>

        
    
        
            <p style="margin-left:10px">
            File: /var/www/html/application/controllers/Sestama.php<br />
            Line: 465<br />
            Function: create_qr         </p>

        
    
        
    
        
            <p style="margin-left:10px">
            File: /var/www/html/index.php<br />
            Line: 315<br />
            Function: require_once          </p>

        
    

</div>
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  imagesx() expects parameter 1 to be resource, bool given</p>
<p>Filename: helpers/portalsdm_helper.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 158</p>


    <p>Backtrace:</p>
    
        
    
        
    
        
    
        
            <p style="margin-left:10px">
            File: /var/www/html/application/helpers/portalsdm_helper.php<br />
            Line: 158<br />
            Function: imagesx           </p>

        
    
        
            <p style="margin-left:10px">
            File: /var/www/html/application/controllers/Sestama.php<br />
            Line: 465<br />
            Function: create_qr         </p>

        
    
        
    
        
            <p style="margin-left:10px">
            File: /var/www/html/index.php<br />
            Line: 315<br />
            Function: require_once          </p>

        
    

</div>
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  imagesy() expects parameter 1 to be resource, bool given</p>
<p>Filename: helpers/portalsdm_helper.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 159</p>


    <p>Backtrace:</p>
    
        
    
        
    
        
    
        
            <p style="margin-left:10px">
            File: /var/www/html/application/helpers/portalsdm_helper.php<br />
            Line: 159<br />
            Function: imagesy           </p>

        
    
        
            <p style="margin-left:10px">
            File: /var/www/html/application/controllers/Sestama.php<br />
            Line: 465<br />
            Function: create_qr         </p>

        
    
        
    
        
            <p style="margin-left:10px">
            File: /var/www/html/index.php<br />
            Line: 315<br />
            Function: require_once          </p>

        
    

</div>
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  Division by zero</p>
<p>Filename: helpers/portalsdm_helper.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 166</p>


    <p>Backtrace:</p>
    
        
    
        
    
        
            <p style="margin-left:10px">
            File: /var/www/html/application/helpers/portalsdm_helper.php<br />
            Line: 166<br />
            Function: _error_handler            </p>

        
    
        
            <p style="margin-left:10px">
            File: /var/www/html/application/controllers/Sestama.php<br />
            Line: 465<br />
            Function: create_qr         </p>

        
    
        
    
        
            <p style="margin-left:10px">
            File: /var/www/html/index.php<br />
            Line: 315<br />
            Function: require_once          </p>

        
    

</div>
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 1 to be resource, bool given</p>
<p>Filename: helpers/portalsdm_helper.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 169</p>


    <p>Backtrace:</p>
    
        
    
        
    
        
    
        
            <p style="margin-left:10px">
            File: /var/www/html/application/helpers/portalsdm_helper.php<br />
            Line: 169<br />
            Function: imagecopyresampled            </p>

        
    
        
            <p style="margin-left:10px">
            File: /var/www/html/application/controllers/Sestama.php<br />
            Line: 465<br />
            Function: create_qr         </p>

        
    
        
    
        
            <p style="margin-left:10px">
            File: /var/www/html/index.php<br />
            Line: 315<br />
            Function: require_once          </p>

        
    

</div>
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  imagepng() expects parameter 1 to be resource, bool given</p>
<p>Filename: helpers/portalsdm_helper.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 172</p>


    <p>Backtrace:</p>
    
        
    
        
    
        
    
        
            <p style="margin-left:10px">
            File: /var/www/html/application/helpers/portalsdm_helper.php<br />
            Line: 172<br />
            Function: imagepng          </p>

        
    
        
            <p style="margin-left:10px">
            File: /var/www/html/application/controllers/Sestama.php<br />
            Line: 465<br />
            Function: create_qr         </p>

        
    
        
    
        
            <p style="margin-left:10px">
            File: /var/www/html/index.php<br />
            Line: 315<br />
            Function: require_once          </p>
```

I already set the /var/www/html/temp and /var/www/assets/images directory mode to 777 and set the owner and its group to apache. If it helps, i am using Codeigniter 3, Linux Centos 9 and Apache. Also this is the actual script that cause the error above :

```
require_once APPPATH . "libraries/phpqrcode/qrlib.php";
    $tempdir = FCPATH . "temp/"; //Nama folder tempat menyimpan file qrcode
    if (!file_exists($tempdir)) //Buat folder bername temp
        mkdir($tempdir);

    //ambil logo
    $logopath = base_url() . "assets/images/Logo-BMKG-new-242x300.png";

    //isi qrcode jika di scan
    $codeContents = $content;
    $filename = date('dmY_his_a', time()) . '_' . $suffix . '.png';
    //simpan file qrcode
    QRcode::png($codeContents, $tempdir . strval($filename), QR_ECLEVEL_H, 10, 4);


    // ambil file qrcode
    $QR = imagecreatefrompng($tempdir . $filename);

    // memulai menggambar logo dalam file qrcode
    $logo = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($logopath));

    imagecolortransparent($logo, imagecolorallocatealpha($logo, 0, 0, 0, 127));
    imagealphablending($logo, false);
    imagesavealpha($logo, true);

    $QR_width = imagesx($QR);
    $QR_height = imagesy($QR);

    $logo_width = imagesx($logo);
    $logo_height = imagesy($logo);

    // Scale logo to fit in the QR Code
    $logo_qr_width = $QR_width / 8;
    $scale = $logo_width / $logo_qr_width;
    $logo_qr_height = $logo_height / $scale;

    imagecopyresampled($QR, $logo, $QR_width / 2.3, $QR_height / 2.3, 0, 0, $logo_qr_width, $logo_qr_height, $logo_width, $logo_height);

    // Simpan kode QR lagi, dengan logo di atasnya
    imagepng($QR, $tempdir . $filename);
    return [base_url() . '/' . $tempdir . $filename, $tempdir . $filename];
```

The `$content` is `FCPATH . "/uploads/mutasi/beritaacara/" . $data['title_pdf']`. Please help me what did i do wrong? How do i make it work? It said that its a permission issue but i already tried to set almost any related directory mode to 777 and its owner & group to apache but still wont work.

Comment: The [imagecreatefrompng](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php) function doesn't write an image file, it reads a PNG file into an image object that you can manipulate. If I'm not mistaken, it looks like you are trying to output a file with this: `imagecreatefrompng(/var/www/html/temp/10012023_053321_pm_qrcode.png)` and it is returning `FALSE`.

Comment: @S.Imp agree, it read the qrcode image created on that path `(/var/www/html/temp/10012023_053321_pm_qrcode.png)` by the syntax above `QRcode::png($codeContents, $tempdir . strval($filename), QR_ECLEVEL_H, 10, 4);`.. i think it throws false because the qrcode image doesnt exist yet because the syntax above that create those qrcode image file failed and throws permission error, or am i wrong to think that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my SELinux is enabled, it's on enforcing mode and my temp folder context is `unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0`. The problem is solved when i set the temp folder context to `httpd_sys_rw_content_t` using `chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t temp`. Thank you guys.